# Ubuntu mounts ISO but some files are unreadable

Tags: mount, iso-image, file-corruption

I'm new to Linux and just installed ubuntu 12.04 amd64 this month. I had failed to install Texlive with texlive2012 iso image.

I used the [recommended command](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html) to mount:

```
mount -t iso9660 -o ro,loop,noauto /your/texlive2012.iso /mnt
```

But the installer failed to read some file. The iso is fine, I checked the md5.
I extracted everything from iso with archive manager and it installed successfully.

So, why mount is not working?

With furius iso mount tool, mount with Fuse, and it installed.
(mount first time, installed with warning, mount again, installed well.)

While mount with Loop, it failed to install.
Updated Error message from terminal, mounted with furius iso mount, loop.

```
texlive2012-20120701_iso$ ./install-tl -gui  
Loading ./tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb  
Installing TeX Live 2012 from: .  
Platform: x86_64-linux =    'x86_64 with GNU/Linux'  
Distribution: inst (compressed)  
Directory for temporary files: /tmp  
Installing [0001/2481, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many [3k]  
Installing [0002/2481, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: 2up [4k]  
Installing [0003/2481, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: Asana-Math [457k]  
Installing [0004/2481, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: ESIEEcv [2k]  
...  
Installing [0265/2481, time/total: 00:10/01:09]: calctab [5k]  
Installing [0266/2481, time/total: 00:10/01:09]: calligra [42k]  
Installing [0267/2481, time/total: 00:10/01:09]: calligra-type1 [59k]  
Downloaded ./archive/calligra-type1.tar.xz, size equal, but md5sum differs;  
downloading again.  
./tlpkg/installer/xz/xzdec.x86_64-linux: (stdin): File is corrupt  
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive  
tar: rmtlseek not stopped at a record boundary  
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now  
untar: untarring /home/lichao/ttt/temp/calligra-type1.tar failed (in /home/lichao/ttt/texmf-dist)  
untarring /home/lichao/ttt/temp/calligra-type1.tar failed, stopping install.  
Installation failed.  
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.  
Or you can restart by running the installer with:  
  install-tl --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]  

./install-tl: Could not write to install-tl.log, so flushing messages to stderr.  
Loading ./tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb  
Installing TeX Live 2012 from: .  
Platform: x86_64-linux =    'x86_64 with GNU/Linux'  
Distribution: inst (compressed)  
Directory for temporary files: /tmp  
Installer revision: 26794  
Database revision: 26935  
Installing [0001/2481, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many [3k]  
Installing [0002/2481, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: 2up [4k]  
Installing [0003/2481, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: Asana-Math [457k]  
Installing [0004/2481, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: ESIEEcv [2k]  
Installing [0005/2481, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: FAQ-en [1k]  
...  
Installing [0262/2481, time/total: 00:10/01:09]: c90 [2k]  
Installing [0263/2481, time/total: 00:10/01:09]: cachepic [5k]  
Installing [0264/2481, time/total: 00:10/01:09]: cachepic.x86_64-linux [1k]  
Installing [0265/2481, time/total: 00:10/01:09]: calctab [5k]  
Installing [0266/2481, time/total: 00:10/01:09]: calligra [42k]  
Installing [0267/2481, time/total: 00:10/01:09]: calligra-type1 [59k]  
Downloaded ./archive/calligra-type1.tar.xz, size equal, but md5sum differs;  
downloading again.  
untar: untarring /home/lichao/ttt/temp/calligra-type1.tar failed (in /home/lichao/ttt/texmf-dist)  
untarring /home/lichao/ttt/temp/calligra-type1.tar failed, stopping install.  
Installation failed.  
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.  
Or you can restart by running the installer with:  
  install-tl --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]  
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am sure that the iso is fine. I can open it with archive manager and all files are good.
But after mounting it, even archive manager failed to open some files (which can be opened when the iso is opened in archive manager).

I think I'll just mount with fuse in the future.

Comment: Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/468525/edit) your question to include the error messages you get. Without them we can't possibly help.

Comment: added error message from install-tl.

Comment: Have you verified that you have enough space in your `/tmp` to extract the files?

Comment: Yes, I installed to /home/xx/tex-xxx before, similar error. Archive manager can't open that error file too.

Comment: Then it sounds like the file `harvard.doc.tar` is broken/corrupt. Can you try to untar it manually and see if tar complains.

Comment: Yes, it may be broken, but only when it's mounted. Open iso in archive manager and it's good.

Comment: Can you please check the md5 sum of the `archive/harvard.doc.tar.xz` file? (should be `5763db1e94fe9def6ce784a04114e899 harvard.doc.tar.xz`). You can try to extract it and check the md5 sum of the tar file (`57401e2b9972567b3025bf1925f1d460 harvard.doc.tar`)

Comment: Please show how you mount the ISO file (the link you provide is broken)

Comment: the md5 of the iso is correct, so everything in the iso should be correct. And it's not always 'harvard.doc', it would be another file if mount again.

Comment: link corrected, also added the command pattern.

Comment: @Chao Yes but checking the md5 of the file would tell us if the mount has problems or your xz or tar programs.

Comment: @Chao Any errors in /var/log/messages?

Comment: I did not see the file: /var/log/messages

Comment: What do you mean with " mounted with furius "

Comment: "furius iso mount tool" is a gui program to mount iso files, I installed it today. It has a mount option of Fuse or Loop.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu provides packages for TeX Live: you don't need to install it manually. Just use the package manager

```
apt-get install texlive-full
```

### Edit

For TeX Live 2012 there are [alternative repositories][1]

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install texlive
```

Or: why not using the official tarball from http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html and follow the installation instructions?

Comment: Yes, but it's texlive2009, not the new texlive2012. And I may use iso files later, so I want know if it's supported or not.

Comment: @Chao Added some alternative repositories

Comment: @Chao Are you *really* sure that the ISO is OK? With which MD5 did you compare it?

Comment: Sorry, I installed too many times, so /tmp is full. That's not the error I mentioned. error message updated. There is error when my disk in **NOT** full. It's file corrupt.

Comment: Not using the ppa or net-install, because of low network speed, and no need to download 2G for reinstall. But it would have worked I guess.